# Can't echo data from database (array), PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

The aim of my code is to get all of the usernames from the database and echo them in ascending order with a break between each one. It seems to work fine apart from the one line.

When I run this code I get the error

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\Site files\users.php on line 23

I've highlighted this line in the code with ** on ether side of it. I've tried lots of ways to make this work but I'm not particularly competent and I can't seem to find a solution.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="comproject"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members ORDER BY username ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
$array[] = $row; }

for ($i=0; $count>$i; $i++) {
    **echo $array[$i] + "<br/>";**
}
?>
```

Also I'm trying to move my code into mysqli so if you have any suggestions on doing that, also good thanks :) I understand its pretty much the same

Comment: In PHP, you use `.` for concatenation, not `+` (as you would in JavaScript). See the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Why are you copying the results of your query into an array, only then to loop over the array and echo its output?  Why not `echo $row[0]` within the `while` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
for ($i=0; $count>$i; $i++) {
  echo $array[$i][0] . "<br/>";
}
```

The issues are:

1. You concatenate string with `.`, and
2. `$array[$i]` is a numerically-indexed array with the first element the username:

`$array` is:

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [0] => UsernameOne
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [0] => UsernameTwo
          )

  )
```

Comment: Perfect, works great thanks. Why was the [0] necessary though?

Comment: Because `$array` is: `Array(0 => Array(0 => UsernameOne), 1 => Array(0 => UsernameTwo))`. So `$array[$i]` is `Array(0 => Username)` and `$array[$i][0]` is `Username`.

Answer (score 5):

In PHP strings are concatenated using `.` not `+`. Try:

```
echo $array[$i] . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks but new error now "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\Site files\users.php on line 23". Also its echoed "Array" over and over. Thats the same line as before by the way

Comment: @Shard `$array` contains arrays. How do you want them displayed?

Comment: @Shard Try: echo $array[$i][0] . "<br/>";

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate strings with `.` not `+`:

```
echo $array[$i]."<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks, read comment on the other answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  with mysqli  like this( code described with comment):

```
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="comproject"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password");
   //check connect error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connection failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


   // run query 
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM members ORDER BY username ASC");
//fetch data
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
       echo $row['username']."<br />";
    }


    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: That looks far more complex than I thought it would, I thought for the most part you could just change my_sql to my_sqli?

Comment: @Shard : do you think so? it is much much easier code than your existing code if you understand it and you also wanted to conversion in mysqli. so i posted this answer.

Comment: yeah I would agree with all of that, I just thought the jump between mysql and mysqli was tiny